# JSF 2 Spring XRebel Huge session

Tags: java, spring, jsf, session

I recently installed the XRebel plugin, which allows you to see current session size.

I discovered, that the session instantly gets to 10 mb on first page load(initialization of the auth session bean.).

To my setup:

I am using JSF 2.2, Spring 4 and Hibernate 4.

DAO Layer > Service Layer > Managed Bean

DAO Layer

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Repository
public class UserDao extends BaseDao<User>
{
...
}
```

Service Layer

```
@Service
@Named
@Singleton
public class UserService extends BaseService<User>
{


    @Autowired
    private UserDao dao;

...

}
```

My auth session bean, that gets loaded on first page load

```
@Named
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class Auth implements Serializable
{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    ...
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml I am using

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />
```

This is a general issue I have when I autowire service beans in my session beans.

The Userservice only contains methods to retreive, save and delete user objects, there is no ArrayList containing users or anything else.

I have two @Autowired Services in my **auth** bean - UserService and SessionService.

If I commment out UserService, SessionService will reach the same size. If I comment out both there is a "DestructionCallbackBindingListener" from "org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttribute..." that reaches 8mb instantly.

What am I doing wrong? How do I decrease the session size ?

I gladly accept any help.

Here is an image of XRebel showing that the userService takes about 8mb size in session. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBXx3.png

Looking at XRebel, it seems that the beanFactory is saved in the user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted in the official forums regarding XRebel. This is the answer I received.

> Indeed, the beanFactory is *reachable* from the session, through the
>   CGLIB proxy. We may need to improve to how we recognize objects that
>   are shared or should not be considered part of the session.
>
> We try to show how much memory each session takes, but Spring
>   beanFactories are of course shared between sessions usually.
>
> Often the fact that we filter out *transient* fields from the session
>   is enough, but we’ll take a look at the CGLIB/Spring proxies to see
>   how we can filter them out by a general rule or maybe we can just add
>   specific Spring classes to an ignore list.

In short: The beanfactory can be Ignored when looking at session size, optionally, if possible mark the autowired services transient.

> Indeed you can ignore it mentally for now or if it’s possible then
>   yes, making the variables transient would exclude them.

Comment: FYI while the shared objects in the session do not matter as a memory leak, they still will create a ton of overhead if your session is serialised, unless they use writeReplace() or similar.

Comment: Is there a way for me to enforce that or is it all related to spring and there is nothing I have to do about that?

Comment: At the moment, nothing could be done, but expect improvements in the next versions of the tool.